# Node.js mysql queries not asynchronized

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to Make a Select statement of 5 rows, then each row will pass to methods and will add the result of each to an array for a call back

My code:

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');
var userReqId,artistId;
 var con;
var result = [];

exports.getNew = function(userRequestedId,callback) {
     con = mysql.createConnection({..});
     userReqId=userRequestedId;

con.query("SELECT * FROM x ORDER BY y DESC LIMIT 5" ,function(err,rows){
   if (err)
   {
    console.error(err);
    callback({'response':'Connection error ','res':false});
    return;
   }

var i;
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
     var idd=rows[i].UserID;
     artistId=idd;
     var recidd=rows[i].RecID;

isLiked(userRequestedId,idd,recidd,rows[i].RecDate,rows[i].Recs,rows[i].RecData,rows[i].RecType,rows[i].CatID,rows[i].RecTitle);

}  //end for loop

 var Data = {"Result":{ "all": result }};



                console.log('JSON-result:', JSON.stringify(result));

        callback(Data);

});
};



function isLiked(userRequestedId,musicianId,recordId,recDate,recLikes,recData,recType,catId,recTitle)
{
      con.query("Select * from x where y="+userRequestedId+" AND z="+recordId+"",function(errrz,rowsszz){ 

            if (errrz) {
    console.error(errrz);
  } 

  if(rowsszz.length>0) { setLiked(true); }
  else {  setLiked(false); }

   getUserInfo(musicianId,recordId,recDate,recLikes,recData,recType,catId,recTitle);
      });



}

function getUserInfo(musicianId,recordId,recDate,lzk,recData,recType,catId,recTitle)
{
       con.query("Select o,i,p  from x where q="+artistId+"",function(errr,rowss){ 
            if (errr) {
    console.error(errr);     
    return;
  }
     usernamee=rowss[0].w;  countryy=rowss[0].y;  levelz=rowss[0].z;
     setParms(usernamee,countryy,levelz);


    pushIt(qs,recordId,recDate,lyi,recData,recType,catId,recTitle);
     }); 



}


///////// Push result ! ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function pushIt(ps,recordId,recDate,zli,recData,recType,catId,recTitle)
{

  console.log('The PUSH ');

     result.push({ 
     x:getU(),
     y: getC(),
     z: getL(),
     w:recordId,
     q: musicianId,
     s: recDate,
    l: recLikes,
     e: recData,
     f: recType,
     y: catId,
     u: recTitle,
     n: getLiked()
     });

}
```

The problem is in the for loop, it just call the first method and goes to the callback, after that it continues the other methods which is wrong!

Comment: `isLiked` is async func but you use it like sync. Use promises or `async` library to avoid callback hell.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/async as @AikonMogwai said